# Intellij -- java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/idea/maven/server/RemoteMavenServer36

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Intellij keeps throwing this error.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/idea/maven/server/RemoteMavenServer36 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Exception in thread "main"
```

Note: Tried jdk difference mentioned in other post. Still, no luck.

Comment: The JVM is too old to run the code you ask it to.

Comment: That means you are using a JVM version less than 8...

Comment: Yes, I'm using java 7.
project is built with 1.7

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem seems to be at the JDK for importer. 
Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220755/8632656 worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is known issue in 2022.2 version, see *[IDEA-298673](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-298673) Error importing maven project (bound to max JDK 1.7)*

The workaround is to define 1.8+ JDK for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **JDK for importer:**.

In later IDE versions, IDE will automatically fallback to the internal JDK for Maven import. Note that this JDK has no relation to the Project JDK which is used to build and run the application.